# Mixing C and assembly sources and build with cmake

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, cmake, avr

I'm using eclipse for building a avr-gcc project that mixes assembly code and C source files.
I want to get rid of the automatic makefile generation of eclipse because I need to automate some process into the makefiles and for other reasons.

I used cmake some times ago and I was happy with it so I want to try to compile my source files using it. Everything run as expected with C sources. The problem is that at the end I need to compile some assembly files (actually 2) and add them to the target.

I googled around but I didn't found a way for doing this. 
someone have an idea on how to do this?

The problem is that in eclipse I have
    -x assembler-with-cpp

added to gcc argument list. I need to find a way for selectively add this param to the standard gcc argument list only for the asm files. I didn't find around any way for doing this.

thank you in advance

SOLUTION:
set in CMakeLists.txt every file to compile in the same list

```
enable_language(C ASM)

set ( SOURCES 
    foo.c
    bar.c
    foobar.s
)

add_executable(program  ${SOURCES} )
```

in the Toolchain file you should place:

```
SET(ASM_OPTIONS "-x assembler-with-cpp")
SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} ${ASM_OPTIONS}" )
```

the second line is just if you need to pass extra options while compiling asm files. I wanted to pass all the CFLAGS plus some ASM_OPTIONS

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what the problem is with compiling the assembler sources?

Comment: I edited my post. please see it for new details. I hope they are enougth for understand what's the problem. thank you again

Comment: I don't understand. You don't want to use Eclipse-generated makefiles, and complain about the Makefile Eclipse writes?

Comment: I don't want to use the auto generated makefiles of eclipse because I need to place the build system in a jenkins enviroment on the server. The auto generated makefile have hardcoded path and isn't suitable for being used in jenkins. The alternatives I found was write my own makefile or use something like cmake. cmake works perfectly for everything. I just have problems compiling asm files. I'm not a cmake guru, I used it in the past for simple projects.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

CMake supports assembler out of the box. Just be sure to enable the "ASM" language in your [project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html). If an assembler source file needs preprocessing, also set the source file's [compilation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) options:

```
project(assembler C ASM)
set_property(SOURCE foo.s APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-x" "assembler-with-cpp")
add_executable(hello foo.s bar.c)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. THis don't work at the moment... I have the problem compiling this file: https://github.com/metormote/hardware/blob/master/basestation_test/src/asf/xmega/drivers/cpu/ccp.s If I use what you wrote the file is called directly by avr-as. I think I need to call the file using avr-gcc for let it preprocess the file.

Comment: Thank you sakra for your comment. I tryed this: set ( ASM_SOURCES 
 xmega/drivers/nvm/nvm_asm.s
 xmega/drivers/cpu/ccp.s
) set_source_files_properties(${ASM_SOURCES} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp") add_executable(xMegaAnalog  ${SOURCES} ${ASM_SOURCES}) the problem is that it looks like the files won't be compiled but just skipped. I don't see them using make VERBOSE=1

Comment: Be sure to enable the ASM language, either by using `project(assembler C ASM)` or `enable_language(C ASM)`.

Comment: this is on top of CMakeLists.txt: Project(XmegaAnalog)
project(assembler C ASM) I tryed to join the 2 in something like Project(XmegaAnalog assembler C ASM) but with no results

Comment: try using `enable_language(C ASM)`.

Comment: I get it working... thank you for your help. with enable_language(C ASM) it try to compile the file but with errors. The solution was placing a new variable with SET in the arch file SET(ASM_OPTIONS "-x assembler-with-cpp") and enabling it for asm sources with SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} ${ASM_OPTIONS}" ). *.s files are in this case receiving the right arguments for compiling nicely.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your solution, one of the simplest solutions is this one-liner:

```
SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp")
```